# data arrays with timeseries and additional y axis c3.js

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I want a timeseries plot with a second y axis with data from 3 arrays:

```
var DATE = ['2020-08-14 09:04:12','2020-08-14 09:04:13','2020-08-14 09:04:14'];
var TEMPIN = [12,6,14];
var PRESS = [2000,1988,2002];
```

But it plots both datasets on y1 and y2 is empty
I want array "DATE" is x and "TEMPIN" data on y1 and "PRESS" data on y2.
What I am doing wrong?

Full code:

```
var DATE = ['2020-08-14 09:04:12','2020-08-14 09:04:13','2020-08-14 09:04:14'];
var TEMPIN = [12,6,14];
var PRESS = [2000,1988,2002];

DATE.unshift('x');
TEMPIN.unshift('data1');
PRESS.unshift('data2');

          var chart = c3.generate({
                bindto: '#graph',
                data: {
                    x: 'x',
                    xFormat: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
                    columns: [
                        DATE,
                        TEMPIN,
                        PRESS
                    ]
                },
                axes: {
                    data1: 'y1',
                    data2: 'y2'
                },
                axis: {
                    y2: {
                        show:true
                    },
                    x: {
                        type: 'timeseries',
                        tick: {
                            format: '%H:%M:%S'
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by moving the "axes:" part into the "data:" and changing

```
data1: 'y1'
```

to

```
data1: 'y'
```

Full code:

```
            var DATE = ['2020-08-14 09:04:12', '2020-08-14 09:04:13', '2020-08-14 09:04:14'];
            var TEMPIN = [12, 6, 14];
            var PRESS = [2000, 1988, 2002];

            DATE.unshift('x');
            TEMPIN.unshift('data1');
            PRESS.unshift('data2');

            var chart = c3.generate({
                bindto: '#graph',
                data: {
                    x: 'x',
                    xFormat: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
                    columns: [
                        DATE,
                        TEMPIN,
                        PRESS
                    ],
                    axes: {
                        data1: 'y',
                        data2: 'y2'
                    }
                },
                axis: {
                    y2: {
                        show: true
                    },
                    x: {
                        type: 'timeseries',
                        tick: {
                            format: '%H:%M:%S'
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```